# object ineheriting from list, attributes pointing to list items

Tags: python, inheritance, optimization, properties

I'm building a python3 object `Foo` that inherit from `list`. Actually, it's a grammatical tagger for language analysis. I need the following behavior:

- object `Foo` must be iterable
- some attributes (strings or integers) are items inside the iterable.
- some attributes are set in the `Foo.__init__()`
- some are set later, inside a `Foo.method()`
- attributes must be encapsulated so that any modification affect items inside the list
- And I must save memory use, so i expect that :

  - `Foo.foo0 is Foo[0]` (not only Foo.attr[0] == Foo[0])

some other attributes do not need to be inside the "list".

I've found a way to do it, but I suspect there must be a cleaner and more pythonic way. Also,any improvement in performance and memory use is welcome. Here is my code :

```
class Foo(list):

    def __init__(self, foo1, foo2):

        # there is 13 attributes
        # setters raise IndexError without this hack :
        [self.append(x) for x in [None]*13]

        # first pack of attribute 
        self.foo1   = foo1
        self.foo2   = foo2
        # ... etc

    # getter and setter for init attributes 
    @property 
    def foo1(self): return self[0]
    @foo1.setter
    def foo1(self,value): self[0] = value
    # same thing for foo2, foo3... etc

    ## getter and setter for other attributes
    @property 
    def bar1(self): return self[10]
    @bar1.setter
    def bar1(self,value): self[10] = value
    # same thing for bar2, bar3... etc

    def method(self, value1, value2):
        self.bar1 = value1
        self.bar2 = value2
        # ... etc

# init object
f= Foo('some string', 'some other string')
# later :
f.method('data', 'more data')

# expected behavior
assert f.foo1 is f[0]
assert f.bar1 is f[10]
```

I'm not sure I'm doing it right.. particularly with this hack:

```
[self.append(x) for x in [None]*13]
```

Can you think of a better way ?

**EDIT** :
After some benchmark, I definitely saved performance thanks to [MartijnPieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) comment :

```
self.extend(None for _ in range(13))
```

Comment: Properties is exactly how I'd do it.

Comment: As for the hack, don't use a list comprehension for the side effects. Use `self.extend(None for _ in range(13))` perhaps.

Comment: I don't get the point of inheriting from a list. If it is just that you want your object to be iterable, implement the iterable interface (mostly the `__iter__`).

Comment: @MartijnPieters : I actually thought i could do that, but I don't understand why it's better.

Comment: @mxdsp: because it avoids creating an extra list object. Your list comprehension creates two additional lists, both with 13 `None` references in them, and then destroys them both again.

Comment: @bgusach : You're right, thanks, I don't need any other method from list. I'll do that.

Comment: It sounds as if you want a mutable named tuple; you want the fixed length and the named access, at the very least. A namedtuple uses properties for exactly the same purpose.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So if I follow bgusach advice, I also need to implement an `extend` method, right ?

Comment: @mxdsp: that depends. If your *external* API (how other code uses this class) doesn't need an `extend()` method, don't add one. If your implementation uses a list object to store the actual values, then use `self._values.extend()` here. Or use `self._values = [None] * 13`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters. I definitely have some reading to do about iterable interface and `extend`. Could you  please show me a code sample ? About namedtuple, I must add that my `Foo` object have others methods and other attributes (that are not stored inside the iterable)

Comment: Sorry, no, comments are not for extended discussion or step-by-step tutoring. I was showing that `namedtuple` uses the same techniques, not that you should use it. Although you are free to subclass a `namedtuple` class and add methods and attributes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103481/discussion-between-mxdsp-and-martijn-pieters).